# Unable to open 2nd app using Custom Intent Action in Android

Tags: android, intentfilter

I have written one application which handles some specific intent filters, here is the manifest of the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.sampleapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.sampleapp.MainActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!-- 1 filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- 2 filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_2" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- default filter -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.company.sampleapp.Seconf=dActivity"
            />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I am calling this application from a second application using following code:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1");
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

i have also tried:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction("com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1");
startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

But everytime,i am getting following exception:

```
07-18 14:22:56.234: E/AndroidRuntime(12051): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1 }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `<data android:mimeType="..."/>` into `<intent-filter>`.

Try with

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.company.sampleapp.ACTION_DO_SOMETHING_1" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Read more about [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

The intent you create can only run Activity from current app.
you can lunch another app using

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872063/android-launch-an-application-from-another-application) form more info